# What is the general solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, terminology

More specifically, does the general solution work for all cases? I am currently learning ordinary different equations but am curious about its meaning in general. Thanks!

Comment: Welll...that's the meaning of *general solution*: it works in all cases, of course. And this means with any initial conditions in accordance with the given diff. equation.

Comment: Wow! That’s really amazing. Thanks.

Comment: But does the general solution work for ALL solutions, even imaginary solutions?!

Comment: If you didn't limitate the generality when searching for the general solution to something, it must be **that** : a general solution, for all cases ! If you made some special case, e.g. working with only real solutions or whatever, then it clearly won't be a GENERAL solution...